# Filling the area between plots after setting X axis limits

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm having difficulty to set X axis specific limits when I plot two curves on the same graph.

My data has two curves (PERMEABILITY and POROSITY) and DEPTH will work like an index. So I managed to plot them on the same graph and to fill the areas between them with some help. Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550],
       'PERMEABILITY': [1000, 800, 900, 600, 200, 250, 400, 300, 100, 200],
       'POROSITY': [0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, 0.10, 0.15, 0.19, 0.10, 0.15]})

f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_xlabel('PERMEABILITY') 
ax1.set_ylabel('DEPTH')
ax1.set_ylim(df['DEPTH'].max(), df['DEPTH'].min())

ax1.plot(df['PERMEABILITY'], df['DEPTH'], color='red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax2.set_xlabel('POROSITY')
ax2.plot(df['POROSITY'], df['DEPTH'], color='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='blue')

# convert POROSITY axis to PERMEABILITY
# value-min / range -> normalized POROSITY (normp)
# normp*newrange + newmin -> stretched POROSITY to PERMEABILITY
z=df['POROSITY']
x=df['PERMEABILITY']
nz=((z-np.min(z))/(np.max(z)-np.min(z)))*(np.max(x)-np.min(x))+np.min(x)

# fill between in green where PERMEABILITY is larger
ax1.fill_betweenx(df['DEPTH'],x,nz,where=x>=nz,interpolate=True,color='g')
# fill between in yellow where POROSITY is larger
ax1.fill_betweenx(df['DEPTH'],x,nz,where=x<=nz,interpolate=True,color='y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I try to set specific limits for X axis, this filled area does not follow the new 'curve size' as you see on the left image below. My result should be like the image on the right (I did this one on Paint). For example, if I add:

```
ax1.set_xlim(0, 1500)
ax2.set_xlim(-0.10, 0.45)
```

[image]

Someone could help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of `nz` converts between the two x axis scales. When you change the two scales by different amounts, you have to change your calculation of `nz`. You'll need to work out how to do that precisely, but here I just eyeballed the slope and offset until it matched.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550],
       'PERMEABILITY': [1000, 800, 900, 600, 200, 250, 400, 300, 100, 200],
       'POROSITY': [0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.19, 0.15, 0.10, 0.15, 0.19, 0.10, 0.15]})

f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_xlabel('PERMEABILITY') 
ax1.set_ylabel('DEPTH')
ax1.set_ylim(df['DEPTH'].max(), df['DEPTH'].min())

ax1.plot(df['PERMEABILITY'], df['DEPTH'], color='red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax2.set_xlabel('POROSITY')
ax2.plot(df['POROSITY'], df['DEPTH'], color='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='blue')

# convert POROSITY axis to PERMEABILITY
# value-min / range -> normalized POROSITY (normp)
# normp*newrange + newmin -> stretched POROSITY to PERMEABILITY
z=df['POROSITY']
x=df['PERMEABILITY']
nz=((z-np.min(z))/(np.max(z)-np.min(z)))*(np.max(x)-np.min(x))*0.6+np.min(x)+450
#                                                          slope ^      offset ^

ax1.set_xlim(0, 1500)
ax2.set_xlim(-0.10, 0.45)
# fill between in green where PERMEABILITY is larger
ax1.fill_betweenx(df['DEPTH'],x,nz,where=x>=nz,interpolate=True,color='g')
# fill between in yellow where POROSITY is larger
ax1.fill_betweenx(df['DEPTH'],x,nz,where=x<=nz,interpolate=True,color='y')
plt.show()
```

Also, it's easier to answer your question if you include all the necessary imports in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, Don Kirby! You already answered my question, but if you allow me, I have one more.  I understood that the offset is df['DEPTH'].max() - df['DEPTH'].min() and the slope should be this offset divided by (df['PERMEABILITY'][0] - df['PERMEABILITY'][9]). Is that right?. But if I  invert my x axis on Porosity, it should be like ax2.set_xlim(0.45, -0.10) and then I don't know how to change this slope equation. Could you show me?

Comment: Even if I change np.min(z) to np.max(z) and vice-versa, I can't get the exaclty plot. Or maybe I understood wrong your 0.6 value and you could show me how you eyeballed this